# Jquery plugin not working after ajax onchange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my code:(Jquery)

```
<script src="./minified/jquery.sceditor.bbcode.min.js"></script>
        <script>            var loadCSS = function(url, callback){
                var link = document.createElement('link');
                link.type = 'text/css';
                link.rel = 'stylesheet';
                link.href = url;
                link.id = 'theme-style';

                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);

                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.onerror = function(){
                    if(callback) callback(link);
                }
                img.src = url;
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var initEditor = function() {
                    $(".new_text").sceditor({
                        plugins: 'bbcode',
                        style: "./minified/jquery.sceditor.default.min.css"
                    });
                };

                $("#theme").change(function() {
                    var theme = "./minified/themes/" + $(this).val() + ".min.css";

                    $(".new_text").sceditor("instance").destroy();
                    $("link:first").remove();
                    $("#theme-style").remove();

                    loadCSS(theme, initEditor);
                });

                initEditor();
            });

        </script>
```

This code is not working after Ajax on change function. My html code is here:
Here is ajax response:

```
    <div id="txtHint" style="margin-left: 160px;">
<textarea class="new_text"  name="about_builder" id="about_builder" style="height:200px;width:600px;">
<?php echo $row_ab['about_builder']; ?>
</textarea></div>
```

problem is after ajax that text area plugin was not working.

Comment: What do you mean by 'This code is not working after Ajax on change function'? What do you expect to happen, what does happen? is there an error?

Comment: You need to bind your `sceditor` again after the ajax call or use delegation to make sure newly added elements are bound automatically.

Comment: yes, sceditor was working before ajax. but after ajax sceditor was not working. only text area was showing

Answer (score 1):

You need to always call `.sceditor` when you add new html using ajax. You also should modify the function to call the `sceditor` on only the newly added element.

```
var initEditor = function(context) { //Add a context parameter to search only from this context
     $(".new_text",context).sceditor({
             plugins: 'bbcode',
             style: "./minified/jquery.sceditor.default.min.css"
          });
     };
```

Your ajax function looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
   //
})
.done(function(data){
   yourContainer.html(data); //When you load the html, you need to insert it into the DOM
   initEditor(yourContainer);//call the sceditor on the newly added element.
});
```

Comment: i am not getting your method @Khanh

Comment: @user3115202: When you append html from ajax, you need to call the `.sceditor` for that new html